# drop down search not working (2 drop down from 2 table and result from another table)

Tags: php

```
<?php 
session_start();
include("header2.php"); 
include("conection.php");
include("modal.php");
$view = array_key_exists('view', $_GET);
if($view && $_GET['view'] == "delete")
{
mysql_query("DELETE FROM linkdetails WHERE linkid ='$_GET[linkid]'");
}

if(isset($_SESSION["adminusername"]))
{
$first = array_key_exists('first', $_GET);
if(isset($_GET['first'])) 
{
}
else
{
$last = array_key_exists('last', $_GET);
$_GET['first'] =0;
$_GET['last'] = 30;
}
if(isset($_POST["button"]))
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM linkdetails where 
ispid='.$_POST[ispid].' && typeid='.$_POST[typeid].'");
}
else
{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM linkdetails LIMIT $_GET[first] , 
$_GET[last]");
}

$resulti= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ispdetails LIMIT $_GET[first] , 
$_GET[last]");

$resultt= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM linktype LIMIT $_GET[first] , 
$_GET[last]");?>

<section id="page">
<header id="pageheader" class="normalheader">
<h2 class="sitedescription">
</h2>
</header>

<section id="contents">

<article class="post">
<header class="postheader">
<h1>Link  Details</h1>
<p>
<p>
<form method="post" action="">
<label for="textfield1"><strong>ISP Name </strong></label>  
<strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select name="ispid" id="select">
  <option value=""> Select ISP</option>
  <?php
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($resulti))
{
echo "<option value='$row1[ispid]'>$row1[ispname] </option>";
}
?>
</select>
<p>
<label for="textfield2"><strong>Link Type </strong></label>  
<strong>
<select name="typeid" id="select">
  <option value=""> Link Type </option>
  <?php
 while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($resultt))
{
echo "<option value='$row1[typeid]'>$row1[typename]</option>";
}
?>
</select>

</strong>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="button" value="View Records" 
onclick="submit" formaction="viewresult2.php"/>
</form>
</p>
</header>
<section class="entry">
</section>
<section class="entry">
</section>
<section class="entry">
</section>
 <section class="entry">
<?php 
if(mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1)
{
?>
<table width="500" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="56"><strong>Link Name</strong></td>
    <td width="56"><strong>Area</strong></td>
    <td width="136"><strong>Contact Details</strong></td>
    <td width="56"><strong>Comments</strong></td>
    <td width="56"><strong>Phone No</strong></td>
    <td width="56"><strong>email</strong></td>
    <td width="56"><strong>Remarks</strong></td>
       <?php
  if($_SESSION["type"]=="admin")
  {
    ?>
    <td width="119"><strong>Action</strong></td>
      <?php
    }
    ?>
    </tr>
  <?php
  $i =$_GET['first']+1;
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 echo "<tr>";

 echo "<td>&nbsp;" . $row['linkname'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>&nbsp;" . $row['area'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>&nbsp;" . $row['contactdetails'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>&nbsp;" . $row['comments'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>&nbsp;" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>&nbsp;" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>&nbsp;" . $row['remarks'] . "</td>";

  if($_SESSION["type"] =="admin")
 {

      echo "<td>&nbsp;
 <a href='viewrecords.php?linkid=$row[linkid]&view=linkdetails'><img 
 src='images/view.png' width='32' height='32' /></a>
 <a href='addnewlink.php?linkid=$row[linkid]&view=linkdetails'>  <img 
 src='images/edit.png' width='32' height='32' /></a>";
       ?>

 <a href='linkmaster.php?linkid=$row[linkid]&view=delete'><img 
 src='images/delete.png' width='32' height='32' onclick="return confirm('Are 
 you sure??')"/></a></td>
<?php
}
echo "</tr>&nbsp;";
$i++;
} 
 if($_SESSION["type"] =="admin")
{
    $first=$_GET['first']-10;
$last= $_GET['last']- 10;

?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php 
if($first <0)
{ 
} 
else 
{ ?>
<a href="linkmaster.php?first=<?php echo $first; ?>&last=<?php echo $last; ? 
>">

<?php 
}
?><img src="images/previous.png" alt="" width="32" height="32" /></td>
    <td colspan="2"><a href="#" onclick="opennewlink(); return false"><img 
src="images/add.png" alt="" width="32" height="32" /></a></td>
      <?php 
$first=$_GET['first']+10;
$last = $_GET['last']+ 10;
?>
    <td><div align="right"><?php 
if($first > mysql_num_rows($result))
{ 
} 
else 
{ ?>
<a href="linkmaster.php?first=<?php echo $first; ?>&last=<?php echo $last; ? 
>">
<?php
}
?><img src="images/next.png" alt="" width="32" height="32" /></div></td>
    <td width="119" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
     <?php
}
?>
  </table>
  <?php
}
else
{
echo "<h2>No Records Found...</h2>";
}
?>
<ul>
<li><a href="addnewlink.php">Add New Link details</a></li>
</ul>
</section>
</article>


</section>

<?php 
}
else
{
header("Location: adminlogin.php");
 }
if($_SESSION["type"]=="admin")
{
include("adminmenu.php");
}
else
{   
include("usermenu.php");
}
include("footer.php"); 
 ?>
```

Dropdown search is not working. When I am submitting the button it retrns without value. displaying the total value not the filtered value.

I think this is not working.

```
if(isset($_POST["button"]))
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM linkdetails where 
ispid='.$_POST[ispid].' && typeid='.$_POST[typeid].'");
```

Any Solution. Cause I'm not any professional  developer.

Comment: Don't know why filtered result is not generating but all others are working fine...page is totally functional.

Comment: mysql_* functions are old, unsecure, deprecated and _removed_ from php7. Switch to mysqli or PDO!

Comment: That query should be fine if you replace the single quotes with double quotes. By the way, do NOT use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated, use `mysqli_*`. Also, use [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: in your last code-snipped you are mixing `"` with `'`.

Comment: also when accessing keys in arrays like $_GET and $_POST you are missing '' around the keys - `$_POST[ispid]` -> `$_POST['ispid']`. Now you have `Use of undefined constant ispid` (it will be working though, because php is smart enough.)

Comment: Turn on error reporting

Comment: there is no error

Comment: So I think no one is here who can tell me what is the actual problem, Some person  pointed on some point which really hove no error.

Comment: I want to use this types of script. @Jeff do you really think changing quotes single ' to '' will solve the actual problem which I'm facing??? Before posting this I have tried those also.

Comment: Yes, the wrong `"` are one reason why your query defenitely fails, because now you will have additional `.` in your query like `ispid='.1.'`. The correct quotes would be like so: `"SELECT * FROM linkdetails where 
ispid=".$_POST['ispid']." && typeid=".$_POST['typeid']`

Comment: _"I want to use this types of script"_ - but you shouldn't. Its old and _very_ unsecure.

Comment: @Jeff Once again I tried with those changes but it also failed.